# How can I extract a numeric suffix from a string with /bin/sh instead of bash?

Tags: shell, sh

I had the following lines working great using bash.

```
   [[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
   ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

unfortunately, I don't have access to bash in this container, I am using /bin/sh

The first line throws an error

```
[[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
ash: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

and I am assuming the second line will not work even if the first did :-(

hostname contains a name that ends with -n where n is a number 0,1,2 etc..

i.e. myapp-0 or myapp-1

I just need the number in the ordinal variable I am creating above.

As I say, in bash it works great, but not using SH shell.

here is the actually shell that's being reported (using /bin/sh as bash is not installed)

```
/ # echo $0
ash
```

Anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basic posix sh doesn't understand `[[` or regular expressions or arrays, no.

Comment: Double square brackets `[[ ... ]]` are a bashism, meaning they are not guaranteed to work on a POSIX compliant shell. If you need to use `sh`, then you need to create a test expression that it recognizes. Additionally, `sh` doesn't know what arrays are either. One final note, in your error message it looks like your shell is actually `ash` -- these distinctions are important because each shell implementation will have its own quirks and caveats. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44916

Comment: This is like asking "why can't a C compiler run my C++ code?" -- it's not supposed to.

Comment: ...I've edited the title to ask your real problem -- not why you get the error in /bin/sh, but how to accomplish your goal with it.

Comment: That said, note that POSIX doesn't require HOSTNAME to be set at all.

Comment: BTW, I see that you haven't accepted answers on _any_ of the questions you've asked on the site. Unless the answers you've received haven't been usable, it's expected to eventually accept an answer -- that way the way the question is displayed is updated to reflect that it has an acceptable solution. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you don't need to use a regex for the job at all.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Be cautious here: a real baseline POSIX sh may not have a HOSTNAME variable at all
[ -z "$HOSTNAME" ] && HOSTNAME=$(uname -n)

suffix=${HOSTNAME##*-}
case $suffix in
  # bad case: we have a nonempty suffix variable, but it has a non-numeric digit
  # this can also happen if the hostname has no dash at all, so the PE did nothing
  *[![:digit:]]*) echo "WARNING: No ordinal hostname suffix found" >&2;;

  # happy case: we have a numeric digit, and we know from the above no nonnumerics exist
  [[:digit:]]*)   ordinal=$suffix;;

  # other case: only way this should be reachable is if the hostname ends with a dash
  *)              echo "WARNING: Empty hostname suffix found -- ends with a dash?" >&2;;
esac

echo "Host ordinal value: $ordinal"
```

This combines two techniques:

- A [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), `${HOSTNAME##*-}`, which deletes everything up to the last `-` in `HOSTNAME`. (Note that POSIX sh specifies fewer parameter expansions than bash includes, so it's important to check for any individual one you might want to use whether it's included in the standardized subset).
- A [case statement](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case) running a glob expression against the results of that operation.